# Why is $\sin(x)=-0.35$ not the same as $x = \sin^{-1}(-0.35)$

Tags: trigonometry

$\sin^{-1}(-0.35) = 0.3576...$ (in radians)
However using the solve function of a CAS, $\sin(x) = -0.35$ (in radians, given that $0\lt x \lt 2\pi$), provides a value of $x = 0.34991...$

If the value of $x$ is positive $0.35$, both methods achieve the same result. Is this a calculator issue or should the negative be put outside the sin function: $-\sin^{-1}(0.35)$ rather than $\sin^{-1}(-0.35)$?

Thanks

Comment: Arcsine has a domain restriction. That's the short version.

Comment: "sin(x) = -0.35 (in radians) given that 0<x<pi" has no solution. And for any $s\in[-1,1],$ $\sin^{-1}(-s)=-\sin^{-1}(s).$

Comment: sorry should have been 0<x<2pi

Comment: It seems likely that you copied your results incorrectly, in one case omitting the negative sign, in another case misplacing the decimal point. (The answer below shows what correct results would be.) If you are still unsure about all this, check your calculations carefully and update the question with what you found.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is simply to do with the domain that the two modes are set to.

Using inverse sine of −0.35 gives only **one** of **two** answers, one of which being -0.3576... radians, in the 4th quadrant. This is because this mode uses a domain (-π ≤ x ≤ π) and gives an answer that is closest to the positive x-axis going clockwise (which happens to be -0.3576...). However when using the a mode such as SolveN to set a domain:

```
SolveN(sin(x) = -0.35, x, 0, 2π)
```

Gives two answers:

x = 3.4991... or x = 5.9256...

x = 3.4991... is an answer in the 3rd quadrant and since the domain is (0 ≤ x ≤ 2π), the angle is measured anticlockwise from the positive x-axis.

I am not entirely sure how you got x = 0.34991... but I assume you just confused the two answers (3.4991 and -0.3576) because they look similar.

The reason you get the same x value for sin(x) = +0.35, is because the answer is in the first quadrant, hence, the closest to the positive x-axis.

Also, it does not matter where you put the negative because sin(-x) = -sin(x)

I hope this helps.